# How to delete selected data from Excel table in dataGridView using C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I want to delete a row by selecting a row in dataGridView in C# windows form, but I want this record to be deleted from the Excel table. In the codes I have written, only the row selected in the dataGridView is deleted. Please help me to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RlR7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFMCa.png)

I used below codes to delete selected row in DataGridView.

```
    .
    .
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    
    namespace Ünistop
    {
        public partial class SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm : Form
        {
            public SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            }
    
            public static DataTable ExcelTabloDondur(string yol)
            {
                DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
                string sorgu = "select*from[Sayfa1$]";
                OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + yol + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                try
                {
                    baglanti.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cekilenveri = new OleDbCommand(sorgu, baglanti);
                    cekilenveri.CommandTimeout = 250;
                    OleDbDataReader oku = cekilenveri.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
                    tablo.Load(oku);
                    oku.Close();
                    baglanti.Close();
                    cekilenveri.Dispose();
                    oku.Dispose();
                    baglanti.Dispose();
                }
                catch
                {
                    baglanti.Close();
                    baglanti.Dispose();
                }
                return tablo;
            }
    
            private void SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable tablo = İlanAraFormu.ExcelTabloDondur("ilanlar.xls");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo;
            }
    
            private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                int secilen = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                plakaNo_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                aracKapasitesi_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                sehir_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                durak_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            }
    
            private void sil_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string yol = "ilanlar.xls";
                OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + yol + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                baglanti.Open();
    
                if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("İlanınızı silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", "İlan Silme", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow secilen in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(secilen.Index);
                        MessageBox.Show("Verdiğiniz ilan silinmiştir.", "İlan Silme", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    }
    
                    plakaNo_txt.Clear();
                    aracKapasitesi_txt.Clear();
                    sehir_txt.Clear();
                    durak_txt.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to share code as text not as image

Comment: @KargWare Hello sir, I am new to Stackoverflow, I don't know how to use it so forgive me. I am re-posting the codes I wrote.

Comment: Hi `nothing` that is why I asked/explained by comment and did to a down vote. Here in the docu of SO you can find more details about [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
.
.
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Ünistop
{
    public partial class SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm : Form
    {
        public SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        public static DataTable ExcelTabloDondur(string yol)
        {
            DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
            string sorgu = "select*from[Sayfa1$]";
            OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + yol + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            try
            {
                baglanti.Open();
                OleDbCommand cekilenveri = new OleDbCommand(sorgu, baglanti);
                cekilenveri.CommandTimeout = 250;
                OleDbDataReader oku = cekilenveri.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
                tablo.Load(oku);
                oku.Close();
                baglanti.Close();
                cekilenveri.Dispose();
                oku.Dispose();
                baglanti.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                baglanti.Close();
                baglanti.Dispose();
            }
            return tablo;
        }

        private void SoforİlanlarıGoruntuleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable tablo = İlanAraFormu.ExcelTabloDondur("ilanlar.xls");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int secilen = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            plakaNo_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            aracKapasitesi_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            sehir_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            durak_txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[secilen].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void sil_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string yol = "ilanlar.xls";
            OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + yol + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            baglanti.Open();

            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("İlanınızı silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", "İlan Silme", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow secilen in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(secilen.Index);
                    MessageBox.Show("Verdiğiniz ilan silinmiştir.", "İlan Silme", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

                plakaNo_txt.Clear();
                aracKapasitesi_txt.Clear();
                sehir_txt.Clear();
                durak_txt.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```